# Angular 2 Router Link Active and Query Params

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-template, routerlink, routerlinkactive

```
  <span [routerLinkActive]="['accent']" [routerLink]="['list']" [queryParams]="skm.path" (click)="ss.resetSearch()"><i class="material-icons view-list">list</i></span>
  <span [routerLinkActive]="['accent']" [routerLink]="['graph']" [queryParams]="skm.path" (click)="ss.resetSearch()"><i class="material-icons view-quilt">view_quilt</i></span>
```

How would I get the [routerLinkActive]="['accent']" to work both with queryParams and without queryParams.

When I remove the [queryParams]="skm.path" the class will be applied with routes such as /list or /graph

And When I add it back it will be applied with routes such as /list?id=1 or /graph?id=2

But I cannot get it to work in both cases does anyone have an idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldnt [queryParams]="skm.path"  be [queryParams]="{param: skm.path}" ? where param is the name of a query parameter defined in the routes

Comment: Btw, if the binded values are static, you can change [routerLink]="['list']"  to routerLink="list". Same goes for the other properties

Comment: I haven't tried it but I'd be interested if `routerLinkActiveOptions` makes a difference - more information [in the docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive)

Comment: Hey @Jota.Toledo let me add that skm.path = {id: 128, previous_card_level: 3, previous_card_level: 4}. skm is a service

Comment: @0mpurdy Thanks, I tried looking in there but the only option was   routerLinkActiveOptions: {exact: boolean} - I tried both true and false with no luck :( . Any other ideas?